# Vue and laravel together email send to gmail

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I have a problem with this code in vue and laravel. I sending information from vue from to laravel component which I want to send me a mail from form. Datas pass from Vue to laravel but laravel get response from catch what is in mail controller.. Why? Can you answer me for this problem?

this is my contact form from vue what pass datas

```
<template>
    <section id="contact-us" class="contact">
        <h1 class="title title-contact">Contact Us</h1>
        <div class="contact-all-wrapper">
        <h2 class="subtitle">Write Us</h2>
        <div class="contact-us-box">
            <div class="submit-form">
                <div class="form-box">
                    <div class="form-border">
                        <form class="form-container">
                            <div class="form-wrapper">
                                <div class="user-box">
                                    <input
                                    type="text"
                                    v-model="name"
                                    required="">
                                    <label>Full name</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="user-box">
                                    <input type="text"
                                    v-model="phone"
                                    required="">
                                    <label>Phone number</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-wrapper">
                                <div class="user-box">
                                    <input type="text"
                                    v-model="email"
                                    required="">
                                    <label>Email</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="user-box">
                                    <input type="text"
                                    v-model="creation"
                                    required="">
                                    <label>Type of creation</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        <div class="user-box mess">
                            <input type="text"
                            v-model="message"
                            required="">
                            <label>Message</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="control btn-wrapper">
                    <button class="button is-link submit-btn" @click="handleSubmit">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="contact-container">
                <h2 class="subtitle">Contact information</h2>
                <ul class="contact-wrapper">
                    <li class="contact-item">
                        <div class="contact-icon-wrapper">
                            <img src="../../assets/mail-icon.svg" alt="" class="contact-icon">
                        </div>
                        <a href="" class="contact-link">info@aweby.online</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="contact-item">
                        <div class="contact-icon-wrapper">
                            <img src="../../assets/phone-icon.svg" alt="" class="contact-icon">
                        </div>
                        <a href="" class="contact-link">+421 907 151 118</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="contact-item">
                        <div class="contact-icon-wrapper">
                            <img src="../../assets/nav-icon.svg" alt="" class="contact-icon">
                        </div>
                        <a href="" class="contact-link">Ružová dolina 25, 821 08 BA</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="contact-item">
                        <div class="contact-icon-wrapper">
                            <img src="../../assets/job-icon.svg" alt="" class="contact-icon">
                        </div>
                        <a href="" class="contact-link">Milionplus s.r.o.</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="contact-item">
                        <div class="contact-icon-wrapper">
                            <img src="../../assets/link-icon.svg" alt="" class="contact-icon">
                        </div>
                        <a href="" class="contact-link">IG & FB</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            name: '',
            phone: '',
            email: '',
            creation: '',
            message: ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        resetValue() {
            this.name = '',
            this.phone = '',
            this.email = '',
            this.creation = '',
            this.message = ''
        },
        handleSubmit() {
            axios.post('api/send-email', {
                data: {
                    'name': this.name,
                    'phone': this.phone,
                    'email': this.email,
                    'type': this.creation,
                    'message': this.message
                }
            }
                ).then(res => {
                console.log(res);
            }).catch(e => {
                console.log(e);
            })
            this.resetValue()
        }
    }
}

</script>

<style lang="scss">

@import '../../css/variables.scss';

.contact {
    background-color: $darkGray;
    margin: 0 -3em;
    padding: 0 3em 3em 3em;
}

.title-contact {
    color: $white;
    margin-top: 1.5em;
    padding-top: 1.5em;
}

.contact-us-box {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.form-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
}

.form-box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 130%;
    padding: 0.3em;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(42,239,186,1) 0%, rgba(28,197,244,1) 100%);
    border-radius: 30px;
    display: block;
    z-index: 2;
}

.form-border {
    margin: 0em;
    align-items: center;
    background: $darkGray;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

.form-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 1em;
}

.user-box {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.mess {
    width: 95%;
    margin: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.error-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    top: -2em;
}

.error {
    color: $red;
    height: 0em;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}

.user-box input {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    margin-bottom: 8vh;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
}

.user-box label {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: .5s;
}

.user-box input:focus ~ label,
.user-box input:valid ~ label {
    top: -20px;
    left: 0;
    color: #03e9f4;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.btn-wrapper {
    width: 130%;
    margin: 1em 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.submit-btn {
    border-radius: 18px;
    color: $whiteSmoked;
    background: rgb(42,239,186);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(42,239,186,1) 0%, rgba(28,197,244,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(42,239,186,1) 0%, rgba(28,197,244,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(42,239,186,1) 0%, rgba(28,197,244,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#2aefba",endColorstr="#1cc5f4",GradientType=1);
}

.contact-container {
    width: 31%;
    position: relative;
    top: -5.3em;
}

.contact-item {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0.5em 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.contact-icon-wrapper {
    width: 20%;
}

.contact-icon {
    width: 48px;
}

.contact-link {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.2em;

    &:visited {
        color: $whiteSmoked;
    }
}


</style>
```

this is my api route from laravel

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\MailController as MailController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider and all of them will
| be assigned to the "api" middleware group. Make something great!
|


Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});*/

Route::post('/send-email', [MailController::class, 'sendEmail']);
```

my controller for mail

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Mail\YourEmailMailable;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class MailController extends Controller
{
    protected $formData;
    public function sendEmail(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $formData = $request->all();


        // Send the email
        Mail::to('example@example.com')
            ->send(new YourEmailMailable($formData));

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Email sent successfully']);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Email could not be sent. Please try again.']);
    }
    }
}
```

mail component

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Content;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Envelope;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class YourEmailMailable extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $formData; // Add a public property to hold the form data

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @param  array  $formData
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(array $formData)
    {
        $this->formData = $formData; // Pass form data to the class
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this
            ->from('your.email@gmail.com') // Sender's email address
            ->subject('Contact Form Submission') // Email subject
            ->view('emails.contact') // Blade view for email content
            ->with([
                'name' => $this->formData['name'], // Pass form data to the view
                'email' => $this->formData['email'],
                'message' => $this->formData['message'],
            ]);
    }
}
```

this is my env file without private information..

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=your_email@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=your_gmail_password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=your_email@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=Your Name
```

I just need to send from vue form data to laravel.

If somebody needs more detail feel free to comment for it and I will edit my question.

Thank you for a help.

Comment: Everything looks fine, but we can't see your email sending config here. What's in your `.env` file for the `MAIL_*` variables? (Don't share API keys or other secrets here)

Comment: I am sorry but I bad explain it. In mail controller catch response from catch code what is in mail controller.

Comment: Ok, so it looks like you're trying to use Gmail to send email. I've never tried to do this from a Laravel app, so I'm not sure what you will bump into, but a couple of things to try: (1) Make sure you `MAIL_FROM_NAME` is delimited with double-quotes as it has a space in it, i.e. `MAIL_FROM_NAME="Your Name"` and (2) if the exception is being caught, try outputting the exception's own message to find out what's going wrong, e.g. `dd($e->getMessage());` in your controller's `catch {}` block